# Counting number of key comparisons in hash table

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

I have a hash table that look like this:

```
0
1 -> 1101 -> 1222 -> 1343  \\ 3 key comparison 
2
3 -> 2973 -> 2588          \\ 2 key comparison
4
```

How many key comparisons are there?
The given answer is 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 but shouldn't it be 3 + 2 = 5?

Comment: The question doesn't state anywhere *"during insertions"*, *"while populating the values"* or similar (I know you haven't quoted any such statement)?  Bit poor.  It's clear that's what's meant because it's consistent with the answer, but it could also make sense to talk about the number of key comparisons if each value's looked up once (9), or if they're deleted in some specific order (e.g. ascending keys = 6)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answer is correct. One possible sequence:

- At first, you have an empty list -> then add 1101 -> no comparison needed.
- Add 1222 -> go to the `1` list, compared it with 1101 -> add it to the end of the list -> 1 comparison.
- Add 1343 -> go to the `1` list, compared it with 1101, 1222 -> add it to the end of the list -> 2 comparisons.
- Add 2973 -> no comparison,
- Add 2588 -> go to `3` list, compared it with 2973 -> 1 comparison.

So, in total, the number of comparison is `0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 1`

Don't know where do you get the 3 + 2 = 5 from? total number of elements?

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't realize that how it works, I thought I was supposed to count it as if I was searching for some number